Estimate Weibull Shape and Scale function from lifetable data in R
I am trying to calculate a Weibull function departing from an actuarial life table using R.
I have tried to transform life table data into individual patient data and then fit a Weibull using flexsurv as one would do for real survival data. I run into problems due to the large dataset (grouped data pasted into single rows and n=1,000,000) I ended up with and due to errors with the time variable (maybe zeros). I tried adding 0.5 to the age, under the assumptions deaths would happen halfway though the year.
IS this conceptually correct?
Help on the subject would be largely appreciated.
Data and code are below (UK life table Males 2020-2022), dx are deaths and lx are exposed:
 library(tidyverse)
    library("flexsurv")
    
    age <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,
                 27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,
                 50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,
                 73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,
                 96,97,98,99,100)
        dx <- c(4314,223,145,117,80,72,68,79,74,74,58,75,102,110,115,166,211,302,402,
                478,496,523,493,571,532,581,659,645,676,737,763,833,921,965,1007,1089,
                1215,1315,1403,1594,1655,1831,1882,2034,2204,2471,2670,2828,3128,3387,
                3669,3890,4242,4411,4834,5131,5551,5980,6394,6957,7598,8193,8899,9627,
                10227,11146,12267,13124,14123,15128,16120,17226,18575,19437,20816,
                22641,25176,26414,28569,30727,32988,34253,35933,36744,37910,38588,
                38994,39190,38134,36390,34389,31265,27806,24249,20136,16414,12471,
                9452,6706,4854,3078)
        lx <- c(1000000,995686,995464,995319,995202,995122,995050,994982,994902,994828,
                994754,994696,994621,994519,994409,994295,994129,993918,993616,993213,
                992735,992239,991715,991222,990651,990119,989537,988878,988233,987558,
                986821,986058,985226,984305,983340,982333,981244,980029,978714,977311,
                975717,974062,972231,970350,968316,966112,963640,960971,958143,955015,
                951628,947960,944070,939828,935417,930584,925452,919901,913921,907527,
                900570,892973,884780,875881,866253,856027,844880,832613,819489,805366,
                790238,774118,756892,738317,718881,698065,675423,650247,623833,595264,
                564537,531548,497296,461363,424619,386710,348122,309128,269938,231804,
                195413,161024,129759,101953,77705,57568,41155,28683,19231,12525,7671)
        data <- data.frame(age,dx,lx)
    
    # Create a data frame with individual-level data
    # Add patient level data for individuals who have died
    ipd <- data[rep(1:nrow(data), data$dx),] # repeat rows for each dead person
    ipd$status <- 1  # death occurred
    
    # Add censored data for those who did not die in each interval
    censored_data <- data
    censored_data$status <- 0 # Alive
    censored_data$alive <- censored_data$lx-censored_data$dx
    censored_data <- censored_data[rep(1:nrow(censored_data),censored_data$alive),]
    censored_data <- select(censored_data, age, dx, lx, status)
    
    # Combine data into a single data frame
    ipd <- rbind(ipd, censored_data)
    
      
    rm(censored_data)
    
    fit <- flexsurvreg(Surv(age, status) ~ 1 , data = ipd,
                dist = "weibull")

# Another try!
# Assume death occurs halfway through the year
    ipd$age <- ipd$age+0.5
  fit <- flexsurvreg(Surv(age, status) ~ 1 , data = ipd,
                dist = "weibull")


Technically, you might consider your data to be "interval censored": you know the range of times within which individuals dies, but not the actual times. With some care, interval censoring can be incorporated into parametric survival models like your Weibull if you format the data and use the Surv() function correctly. That said, for a large number of time intervals like this you might do just as well proceeding as you suggest by adding 0.5 to each starting time; that also gets around the fact that your parametric model can't handle events at time=0.
Instead of replicating a million individuals yourself, you could take advantage of the "weights" argument (available in survreg() and I suppose also in flexsurvreg(), although I haven't checked). That was designed just for this purpose. The weights would be your dx values, the number who died at each time, for times up to 100 for which event=1. You would also have to have a row for those still alive at the end, with that still-living number as the weight but with an 'event` value of 0.
As these are numbers per million, recognize that the standard errors will be based on having exactly 1 million individuals in the study.

Hi @EdM, thank you for the detailed answer. I have implemented your suggested approach. I did eliminate the value at age zero because I do not need it and simplifies comparing the survival curve directly extracted from the life table. Added the row with survivors at the end. Ne data frame: age, status (1=death, 0=alive) and weights (number of deaths, alive at the end). `# Fit the Weibull parametric model
fit <- survreg(Surv(age, event = status > 0) ~ 1, data = df, weights = weight, dist = "weibull")
Extract the estimated parameters
shape <- 1 / fit$scale
scale <- exp(fit$coefficients)`

@r1000 when child mortality is high, as it used to be in the UK and still is in many countries, the hazard of death as a function of age has a "bathtub" shape: high at the lowest and highest ages, but lower at intermediate ages. A Weibull distribution can't fit such a hazard pattern, as it assumes a monotonic relationship between hazard and time. Omitting that first year in these UK data might improve the Weibull fit to the rest of the data. Even for post-childhood survival, the Gompertz distribution might be a better choice than Weibull.
